# For loop to dynamically output field names

Tags: templating, forloop, variable

I have a set of fields:

```
fieldName1
fieldName2
fieldName3
fieldName4
fieldName5
```

and I want to be able to create a `for` loop something like this:

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
    {% if entry.fieldName ~ i|length %}
    …
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've seen other answers mention the `attribute` function, but when I try something like this:

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
    {% if entry.attribute(_context['fieldName' ~ i])|length %}
    …
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get:

> Key "fieldName1" for array with keys "entry, variables, craft, currentSite, currentUser, siteName, siteUrl, systemName, view, devMode, … i, _key" does not exist.

How should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try like this, attribute you seek is twig function not from the craft entry value.

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
 {% set field = attribute(entry,'fieldName' ~ i) %}
 {% if field is defined and field|length %}
    …
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```